# how to send jsp array to Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

Is there a way to return an array of strings from jsp to Ajax?
How can I send it to the Ajax and read it as

```
xmlhttp.responseText
```

Comment: Can I suggest employing jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and you'll need to convert to http://www.json.org/

Comment: Do you want to send a (java) array of strings from the server to the client via Ajax or o you want to send a (javascript) array of strings from client to server via ajax?

Comment: Related: [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax) Don't use JSP for "raw" Java code.

Comment: Nivas, yes i would like to send the array of strings from the server to the client so i can display it to the the client...

Comment: The best way to do is as in @emboss' answer: JSON is the best to go about it. There are tons of libraries available for parsing json on client as well as the server side. Just google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you look into [JSON](http://json.org/java/) as your transport format. Encode your Java String array into JSON and send this to your Javascript. It's a very lightweight format and there exist tons of Javascript frameworks (jQuery, mootools, dojo, you name it) that make working with it a pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

DWR can be used to send array of strings to AJAX .

[Using DWR for AJAX example](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+DWR+for+AJAX)

[Easy Ajax for Java (DWR)](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)